# How to check if a class has an attribute with `'attr' in instance` syntax

Tags: python, class, python-dataclasses

I want to be able to use the `'attr' in instance` syntax to check if my dataclass has the specified attribute but I can't seem to make it work.

What I want is same behavior as this example with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
print('a' in df)
```

```
True
```

But just for a custom dataclass

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User:
    email: int
    password: str
    blocked_at: float = None
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)

user = User('email@test.com', 'password')

print(user['email'])

'email' in user
```

```
email@test.com

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 'email' in user in User.__getitem__(self, item)
      7 def __getitem__(self, item):
----> 8     return getattr(self, item)

TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that you didn't define the correct hook. You want to implement the [`__contains__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).

Because you didn't, the `in` operator switches to the fallback mode: iterating over the object **as if it was a sequence**, so it tries `object[0]`,then `object[1]`, etc. until it hits an `IndexError` or finds something that is equal to the value you were testing for. Hence, the exception, as `item` is `0`.

Use `hasattr` instead of `getattr`, as you want a *boolean* result. And for your `__getitem__`, you want to make sure you turn `AttributeError` exceptions into `KeyError` exceptions, to keep the interface consistent:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class User:
    email: int
    password: str
    blocked_at: float = None

    def __getitem__(self, item: str) -> str | int | float | None:
        try:
            return getattr(self, item)
        except AttributeError:
            raise KeyError(item) from None
    
    def __contains__(self, item: str) -> bool:
        return hasattr(self, item)
```

Demo:

```
>>> user = User('email@test.com', 'password')
>>> print(user['email'])
email@test.com
>>> 'email' in user
True
>>> user["nonesuch"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 12, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'nonesuch'
```

See the [Python reference section on membership test operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) for the details on how `in` will fall back to iteration:

> For user-defined classes which do not define `__contains__()` but do define `__iter__()`, `x in y` is `True` if some value `z`, for which the expression `x is z or x == z` is true, is produced while iterating over `y`. If an exception is raised during the iteration, it is as if `in` raised that exception.
>
> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index `i` such that `x is y[i] or x == y[i]`, and no lower integer index raises the `IndexError` exception. (If any other exception is raised, it is as if in raised that exception).